# SQL Server not finding serialization assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, sql-server-2008, serialization, sqlclr

I'm trying to deploy an **UpdateContries** SQL CRL Procedure which calls a Web Service, following help found here

- http://www.elzaris.co.za/using-web-services-in-sql-server-clr-assemblies/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84b1se47.aspx
- footheory.com/blogs/bennie/archive/2006/12/07/invoking-a-web-service-from-a-sqlclr-stored-procedure.aspx

So basically I have a Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project on Visual Studio 2010 with a simple Procedure that calls an external Web Services which was added as a Web Reference.

I've copied the project to the remote server that holds the SQL Server 2008 database.

In the project properties I've set the **Generate serialization assembly** to "On", set the **Database Permission Level** to "External" and I have **Deploy Code** activated.

Also in the project I manually create and drop the serialization assembly as follows:

**PreDeployScript.sql**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.assemblies WHERE [name] = N'ReportsWebServicesXML')
    DROP ASSEMBLY [ReportsWebServicesXML];
GO
```

**PostDeployScript.sql**

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [ReportsWebServicesXML]
    FROM 'E:\Projects\Reports\ReportsWebServices\ReportsWebServices\bin\Debug\ReportsWebServices.XmlSerializers.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO
```

The project Build and Deploys successfully, I can see both **ReportsWebServices** and **ReportsWebServicesXML** in the Visual Studio 2010 Server explorer under the Assembies folder but when I attempt to run the procedure it still return the following error:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateContries, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "UpdateContries": 
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot load dynamically generated serialization assembly. In some hosting environments assembly load functionality is restricted, consider using pre-generated serializer. Please see inner exception for more information. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: LoadFrom(), LoadFile(), Load(byte[]) and LoadModule() have been disabled by the host.
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoadImage(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence evidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean fIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence securityEvidence)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] 
...
System.InvalidOperationException: 
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
...
```

Any hints?

Comment: Without wishing to be unhelpful, the error message is fairly specific and Googling it gives several hits about web services and XML serialization, which seems to be relevant to your situation. Have you already reviewed that information (there is even a Microsoft KB article) and if so what have you tried/learned? It might help to avoid people posting suggestions that you have already tried out.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that on the opening message. I followed the instructions on the three links religously, than reviewed my steps and tried to find hints on the comments that follow the tutorials. I've also searched directly by the error message and all the help I found pointed to the serializer not being deployed on the database, but as I told, it is deployed because I can see it in the Assembly folder, both using the VS2010 Server Explorer or the SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution here...
http://www.cstruter.com/blog/320

"When the serialization setting is set to auto/on and you're consuming a webservice in your project, a serialization assembly automatically gets generated in your output folder (e.g. SourceAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll) which you'll need to register in SQL like seen in the following snippet:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY CLRProcedures FROM 'C:\demos\CSTruter.com\CLRSQL\bin\Release\SourceAssembly.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY CLRSerializer FROM 'C:\demos\CSTruter.com\CLRSQL\bin\Release\SourceAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS EXTERNAL NAME [CLRProcedures].[CSTruter.com.StoredProcedures].[Test]"
```