# C# SQL CLR Project - Public Generic.List items show up as non-public members in debugger

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclr

I'm having an issue in a C# SQL CLR project where publicly declared Generic.List items are not showing up as public in the debugger.  This is problematic because I'm trying to serialize the object to XML.  The real project has some complex objects, but a very simple example would be something like this:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void DoSomething()
{

    // the Thing Object has a public property of List<string> 
    // that is created in the constructor
    Thing t = new Thing();

    t.Items.Add("test");
    t.Items.Add("test2");

    // now, if I look at t in the debugger, it has given the
    // items list a capacity of 4 and shows the items as
    // non-public members (2 with values and 2 that are null)

}
```

I wanted to post an image from the debugger here, but it appears I cannot do that as a new user...

With all of that said, is this behavior because it is a SQL CLR project?  The same code worked fine when developing in a console application (though I guess I could have messed something up when adding it to the CLR project).

Adding additional detail on the Thing object - it includes the following declaration for the Items:

```
public List<string> Items { get; set; }
```

Then, in the debugger, the Items just shows Capacity and Count (no actual items or properties for the Items).  The actual item instances are listed under Non-Public members.

Comment: Are you looking at the `Items` property, or the internal/private backing array?

Comment: Original post has been updated to clarify Blorgbeard's question.  So, I'm accessing the Items property (but unable to see them as public members in the debugger, which means the xmlserializer can't see them either).

Comment: You're getting an error with XML serialisation?

Comment: Not an error, just no values.  Even though my items are public, in the CLR project, the actual instances in the list are non-public (and therefore don't get serialized).

Comment: It means no such thing, so the problem you're having serialising likely has another cause; serialisation does not work the same way as debuggers when it comes to indexed properties - the property is public, but it doesn't return a value without an index being passed, so it can't be queried by a debugger unless the debugger supports using a proxy to query something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Items` property itself can never be seen by a debugger, because it is an indexed property, so there isn't a value you can just *get* for it, and hence examining the value it returns doesn't make sense (like examining the 30th of February or a politician's kept promises; it just doesn't exist).

`List<T>` uses the `DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute` attribute to define another class to be used to give a debugger eye view. This class (one internal to mscorlib) has a public `Items` property that returns an array with a copy of the list's items, so that it looks like you can actually examine the `Items` property of `List<T>` when really you are examining the `Items` property of an object that copies out the items when invoked.

Debuggers don't have to use this approach, so maybe the one you are using doesn't, or there's some other restrictions, but if you are using a debugger that doesn't support `DebuggerTypeProxy` you can just examine the private member that stores the items in an array (the array will be at least as large as `Count`, and possibly a bit larger to leave growing room rather than resizing on each `Add`; you can ignore elements beyond `Count - 1`).

This has nothing to do with XML serialisation, so whatever problem you are having with that is likely completely unrelated.

Edit:

I see some people are having other problems with XML serialisation and the SQL CLR as per these:

[SQL Server not finding serialization assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484388/sql-server-not-finding-serialization-assembly)

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753005/when-deploying-a-sqlclr-assembly-with-a-generated-xmlserializer-assembly-the-xmlserializer-assembly-should-be-deployed

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3fa5dce3-b0f3-44f8-9b7b-65439f1c98ae/cannot-deploy-xmlserializers-clr-assemblies?forum=ssdt

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6560fa4-76f1-4da2-b795-7926d0743baa/sql-clr-problem-with-xmlserializer?forum=sqlnetfx

Your XML problem is indeed different to your debugger view issue. (I meanwhile am off to add debugger proxies to some of my collection types, I've always figured people would just skip through to the inner members and not care, but you've made me rethink that one).

Comment: Jon - thanks for the insight.  This sounds very close to the behavior that I'm seeing, but I still think there is an issue (or limitation in the CLR project type).  You are correct that I can inspect the private _items collection, but the Public Items are not there.  The same object can have a Public string x, and it will serialize fine.  However, the Public List<string> will not.  The same object definition behaves differently in a console or winform project than it does in the CLR project.

Comment: I wish I could post a screen shot because it shows very different run-time behavior between the different project types.

Comment: @user3242103 you can post it to any image uploading service and add a link to it as a edit to your original question, a user with more rep will come along and edit your question and turn the link in to a full image.

Comment: Jon - my actual code was quite a bit more complex (and apparently buggy) than the simplified example.  I started a new project from scratch and used the simplified example - The debugger behavior is the same, but it is serializing correctly.  This matches your explanation and means I have a deeper issue in my actual code.  I was sure it was something else, simply because the debugger view seemed to match my issue in addition to the fact that the debugger behaved differently for Console or WinForm projects.

Comment: Debuggers can be trickster tools; they're extremely useful, but I think we've all at some point spent time trying to fix an artefact of debugger behaviour we were mentally conflating with the actual problem that had us using the debugger in the first place. Still, thanks for insight into how others use debuggers (I often use a debugger that never uses the proxies so I forget about them, but I should think more about those users who expect them). Best of luck with your serialisation problem.